# Erik the Slayer is Invisible

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I found a glitch where the Erik the Slayer follower in Skyrim is invisible, but he can still be activated and interacts with enemies and such perfectly fine. He will also reappear randomly, but unfortunately I was not able to get a picture of this.

I've tried looking up the glitch online but all I can find are cases where he is missing entirely and is taking up a slot in their group.

Picture reference:

[image: Picture of an invisible person]

I am using mods, but he was working fine with the mods I was using and only recently started having this glitch, and I haven't changed my mods.

This glitch happened right after the Companions initiation quest where you become a werewolf and teleport to the Silver Hand hideout, and I feel that may have caused the issue.

One notable mod that could have affected him is a start a new life mod where I chose to be reborn as Erik's childhood friend, I also have the Extensible Follower Framework mod.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: Does this problem happen without mods?  No?  Then it's one of your mods.  Disable them one at a time until it fixes this.  Then you know which one causes it.

Answer (score 4):

After a bit of testing I have found a fix to the problem, it is a combination of low draw distance and a mod that I had completely overlooked, which was an HDT extension for the Capes of Skyrim mod, it occasionally has a glitch where it can stretch out a fair distance or get "stuck" on an object, which would mean that the game assumes the cape is part of the player model, and would phase him out due to low draw distance.

Removing and replacing his cape from his inventory fixes the problem, it could also be fixed by increasing the draw distance.